# Class org.eclipse.fx.core.guice.FXLoggerListener does not implement the requested interface com.google.inject.spi.TypeListener

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

After installing e(fx)clipse in eclipse Oxygen.2 (4.7.2) from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen, I get that error very often. When I try to create a new simple java project, or when I try to clean the workspace, save, build, etc... I am using Fedora 26. It always seems to be the same error:

> java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class
>   org.eclipse.fx.core.guice.FXLoggerListener does not implement the
>   requested interface com.google.inject.spi.TypeListener

I can't seem to find an answer on how to fix that... I tried deleting the workspace and creating a new one but that didn't work.

Edit 1: I am using openjdk version "1.8.0_151"

Edit 2: Error log
https://hastebin.com/yedubevedi.swift

Edit 3: This is the entire message that appears on the error window's details

> An internal error occurred during: "Updating project 'Test'".
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError:
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError:
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError:
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError:
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError:
>   java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class
>   org.eclipse.fx.core.guice.FXLoggerListener does not implement the
>   requested interface com.google.inject.spi.TypeListener

Comment: I just installed e(fx)clipse (version 3.0.0.201705220750) on the same version of Eclipse as you and it seems to be working fine on Windows 10. Can you replicate the failure and update your post with a bigger stack trace? Also, review the error log: Help -> About Eclipse -> click Installation Details -> Configuration tab -> click View Error Log. Anything relevant there?

Comment: I editted my question. Also, on my windows machine, I have Ogxygen.2 (4.7.2) too, and I have no issues there. e(fx)clipse (version 3.0.0.201705220750), which is the same version as the one installed on my fedora laptop...